# Conv2D + LSTM network giving errors

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have a list of matrices called charMatrixList, of length 40744. I convert this list to numpy array, and the shape changes to (40744,32,30). This numpy array is passed as an input to the neural network.

The errors I'm getting are related to the shape of the Conv2D layer output, when passed as an input into an LSTM layer.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Embedding,LSTM,Flatten,Conv2D,Reshape
import numpy as np


def phase22(charMatrixList ):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1,1) , padding="same",               activation="relu",input_shape=(40744,32,30)))
    model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
    input_array = charMatrixList
    model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
    output_array = model.predict(input_array)
    return output_array

p2out = phase22(charMatrixList)
```

I'm getting the below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-56-f615f91b6704>", line 1, in <module>
    p2out = phase22(np.array(charMatrixList) )

  File "<ipython-input-55-9a4fd292a04f>", line 4, in phase22
    model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True))

  File "C:\Users\Kishore\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 185, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])

  File "C:\Users\Kishore\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py", line 500, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Kishore\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)

  File "C:\Users\Kishore\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 311, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_11: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras ignores the first dimension when defining input size because that is just the number of training examples, m. Keras is able to work with any m, so it only cares about the actual input dimensions. That is why Kears sees (40744,32,30) as 4 dimensions.

I'm confused by the dimensions of your input, is 40744 the number of training examples? If it is do input_size = (32, 30).

If your input has 3 dimensions include number of training examples in your input, ie. charMatrixList = (m, 40744,32,30)

Comment: Thanks for the response!! 40744 is indeed the number of training examples. But once I changed the input_size is changed to (32,30) , I'm getting an error : ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3.  

Moreover, isn't the error mentioned in the question related to the LSTM layer ?

Comment: Your conv2D output and LSTM input have mismatched shapes. Conv2d expects 4-d arrays as inputs (m, height, width, # of channels) and outputs 4-d. LSTM expects 3-d inputs (m, time steps, sequence length) and can output 2d or 3d.

Comment: Thanks BlueSkyz !! 
So what kind of reshape layer can I add after the Conv2D layer and before the LSTM layer ? In order to modify the shape of 4D output to 3D.

Now the execution is crossing the conv2d stage, which looks as follows:

 model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1,1) , padding="same", ativation="relu",input_shape=(32,30,1)))