# ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 3, 3, 128)

Tags: python

I am working on a double task model to distinguish handwritten digits and their chirographies, but there is a problem in merging convolution layer and sharing the parameters. How do I need to modify my model?
Here is my code of model:

```
write_input = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name='write_input')
num_input = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name='num_input')

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(num_input)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)

y = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(write_input)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
y = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
y = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(y)

merge = Concatenate()([x, y])
merge = Bidirectional(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True))(merge)

x = Flatten()(merge)
x = Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu')(x)
output_01 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='output01')(x)

y = Flatten()(merge)
y = Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu')(y)
y = Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), activation='relu')(y)
output_02 = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='output02')(y)
```

Comment: The dataset I use is a handwritten digital images similar to MINST, and its label includes what it is and who wrote it

Comment: keras need a batch size for input use this code to add batch size  `np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)`

Comment: keras API input shape of 4 for Conv2D later (batch_size,image x , image y, chanel)

Comment: well ,need i change the bidirectional layer? the ndim of the input from the conv2D is 4 while the LSTM expect 3.  So is it better to just delete the bidirectional layer or is there a layer which can recieve a 4 -ndim input?

Comment: i havent use LSTM but i found this https://stackoverflow.com/q/56506305/13319197